# How to enable audio sound effects in live chat or bot chat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

Good Morning..

After Google Chrome has updated its autoplay policy in April 2018 to prevent playing audios & videos without user interacting, How can i start sound effect to notify user with the new messages ?

I don't want to autoplay audio, all i want is to play sound effect everytime user got a new message from the other line.

Here is my snippet code as a simple on what i need to achieve:

```js
function sendMessage(msg, callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('audio').play();
    var msg_body = document.createElement('div');
    msg_body.innerText = msg;
    document.querySelector('#chat-body').appendChild(msg_body);
    if(callback) callback();
  },2e3);
}

sendMessage('Hello', function(){
  sendMessage('Good Morning', function(){
    sendMessage('What\'s Your Name ?');
  });
});
```

```css
#chat-body > div{border-radius:10px;background-color:#EEE;margin:10px;padding:10px}
```

```html
<div id='chat-body'></div>
<audio src='https://notificationsounds.com/notification-sounds/plucky-564/download/mp3'></audio>
```

Play function may work correctly on *stackoverflow.com* because of its high engagement rate, but in my page and even on *[Codepen.com](https://codepen.io/MoSaleh404/pen/ERJdGB)* audio not plays and console returns error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. goo.gl/xX8pDD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let audio element be muted, and make an unmute button for user:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#audiovideo_elements

```
<audio id="audio" muted>
<button id="unmuteButton"></button>

<script>
  unmuteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    audio.muted = false;
  });
</script>
```